# How to upload audio to soundcloud via my android app using retrofit 2

Tags: android, upload, retrofit, soundcloud

I'm trying to upload my .mp3 file to `soundcloud` using this `retrofit2` interface :

```
public interface ApiInterface {
@Multipart
@POST("tracks?client_id=********&client_secret=********")
Call<ResponseBody> uploadTrack(@Part("track") RequestBody file, @Part("track[title]") String title, @Part("track[sharing]") String sharing);
}
```

and realization with interceptor to include token:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initComponents();

    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(getApplicationInfo().name, MODE_PRIVATE);
    token = sharedPreferences.getString(Config.ACCESS_TOKEN, "");

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Config.API_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(createOkHttpWithAuth())
            .build();
    apiInterface = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
}
private OkHttpClient createOkHttpWithAuth() {
    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    } else {
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.HEADERS);
    }
    return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(new SoundcloudInterceptor(token))
            .addNetworkInterceptor(interceptor)
            .build();
}
```

Getting response:

```
            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Music/test.mp3");

            // create RequestBody instance from file
            RequestBody requestFile =
                    RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);

            // MultipartBody.Part is used to send also the actual file name
            MultipartBody.Part body =
                    MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("audio", file.getName(), requestFile);

             Call<ResponseBody> call =  apiInterface.uploadTrack(requestFile, "Test", "private");
             call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {

                 @Override
                 public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                     //Log.v("Upload", "success" + response.body().toString());
                 }

                 @Override
                 public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                     Log.e("Upload error:", t.getMessage());
                 }
             });
```

After request i'm receiving error 500:

```
05-13 12:36:23.407 6540-7186/com.example.soundcloud_app_android D/OkHttp: <-- 500 Internal Server Error https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?client_id=**********&client_secret=**********&oauth_token=********** (3455ms)
05-13 12:36:23.407 6540-7186/com.example.soundcloud_app_android D/OkHttp: Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept, Authorization, Content-Type, Origin
05-13 12:36:23.408 6540-7186/com.example.soundcloud_app_android D/OkHttp: Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE
05-13 12:36:23.408 6540-7186/com.example.soundcloud_app_android D/OkHttp: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
05-13 12:36:23.408 6540-7186/com.example.soundcloud_app_android D/OkHttp: Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Date
05-13 12:36:23.408 6540-7186/com.example.soundcloud_app_android D/OkHttp: Cache-Control: no-cache
05-13 12:36:23.408 6540-7186/com.example.soundcloud_app_android D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
05-13 12:36:23.408 6540-7186/com.example.soundcloud_app_android D/OkHttp: Date: Fri, 13 May 2016 09:34:26 GMT
05-13 12:36:23.408 6540-7186/com.example.soundcloud_app_android D/OkHttp: Server: am/2
05-13 12:36:23.408 6540-7186/com.example.soundcloud_app_android D/OkHttp: Status: 500 Internal Server Error
05-13 12:36:23.408 6540-7186/com.example.soundcloud_app_android D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 60
05-13 12:36:23.408 6540-7186/com.example.soundcloud_app_android D/OkHttp: OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1463132179952
05-13 12:36:23.408 6540-7186/com.example.soundcloud_app_android D/OkHttp: OkHttp-Received-Millis: 1463132183407
05-13 12:36:23.408 6540-7186/com.example.soundcloud_app_android D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP
```

Also tried passing `file` and `MultipartBody.Part`. In case of multipart i`m receiving error 422. So what is the right way to upload audio to soundcloud? I guess that i'm passing audio in wrong format and server doesn't recognise it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here example for upload image with retrofit 2.
First, when create retrofit for multipart request, doesn't add converter factory.

```
public static APIMultipartService getMultipartService() {
    if (multipartService == null) {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(DOMAIN)
                .build();
        multipartService = retrofit.create(APIMultipartService.class);
    }
    return multipartService;
}
```

Second, use RequestBody in interface.

```
public interface APIMultipartService {
    @POST("/api/v1/job/photo/add")
    Call<ResponseBody> uploadJobPhoto(@Body RequestBody body);}
```

And here example for create request body with file.

```
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);

                MultipartBuilder builder = new MultipartBuilder().type(MultipartBuilder.FORM);
                builder.addFormDataPart("pic", "photo.png", body);
                builder.addFormDataPart("jobId", id);
                builder.addFormDataPart("privateKey", privateKey);

                Call<ResponseBody> request = ApiService.getMultipartService().uploadJobPhoto(builder.build());
                request.enqueue(callbackPhotoRequest);
```

Try like that, maybe help you.

Comment: Can you debug server side? Maybe problem is there. Cause 500 Error is not a client-side problem.